# How to get the original of the e-mail in Lotus Notes 8.5?

Tags: lotus-notes

How can I see the "original" of an e-mail in Lotus Notes 8.5?

UPDATE:
with "original" I meant "full headers" -> http://kb.iu.edu/data/akij.html

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: "full headers" - http://kb.iu.edu/data/akij.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To see the full headers do  the following:

1. Open the mail message
2. From the View menu choose Show -> Page Source

Answer (score 2):

Open the email. Goto View>Show>Page Source

Answer (score 0):

To see the email source:

1. Open the email
2. Check View > Advanced Menus
3. View > Show > Page Source